# How many delivery attempts will there be if "Maximum delivery attempts" not set

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

A subscription's configuration is shown below. Max delivery attempts is not specified. How does PubSub determine the maximum number of delivery attempts for this setup?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no dead letter policy and therefore no maximum delivery attempts set, then message delivery is attempted until the message is acknowledged or until the message retention duration has passed for the message. There is no set number of times.